# Responsive menu not closing on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little hamburger menu with some Javascript. It works perfectly but I want the menu to close when you press a link (home, about, work, projects), because it's used on a one pager.

Can someone help me out please?

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>The Logo</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/LexGraphicMedia/pen/zYYJJOy)

Comment: Your question not belong to java tag

Comment: Quoting the words of Certain Performance, Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question

Comment: You forgot to include your CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the following as a starter. Essentially you add a click handler to the navlink a tags and check to see if the nav is currently out by looking for the appropriate `nav-active` class. If it is found, then reverse the animations by removing the relevant classes you added to expand the menu.

```
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li a");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
      if(nav.classList.contains('nav-active')) {
        nav.classList.remove(`nav-active`);
        burger.classList.remove(`toggle`);
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
          if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = ``;
          } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
              0.3}s`;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

The complete JS from your codepen:

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(`.burger`);
  const nav = document.querySelector(`.nav-links`);
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li a");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
      if(nav.classList.contains('nav-active')) {
        nav.classList.remove(`nav-active`);
        burger.classList.remove(`toggle`);
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
          if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = ``;
          } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
              0.3}s`;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  // Nav animation
  burger.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    nav.classList.toggle(`nav-active`);

    // Links animation
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = ``;
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
          0.3}s`;
      }
    });

    // Burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle(`toggle`);
  });
};

navSlide();
```